# Find top 5 property of JSON object in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i have a JSON Object like below out of this i want top 5 properties order by date.

```
var json={"09/03/14":"63.7","09/02/14":"67.4","09/01/14":"67.4","08/29/14":"67.4","08/28/14":"69.4","08/27/14":"69.4","08/26/14":"178","08/25/14":"16.8","08/22/14":""}
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want them sorted in ascending date order:

```
var json = {
    "09/03/14": "63.7",
    "09/02/14": "67.4",
    "09/01/14": "67.4",
    "08/29/14": "67.4",
    "08/28/14": "69.4",
    "08/27/14": "69.4",
    "08/26/14": "178",
    "08/25/14": "16.8",
    "08/22/14": ""
}
var arr = [];
for (d in json) {
    arr.push({
        date: new Date(d),
        d: d,
        v: json[d]
    });
}
arr.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.date < b.date) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (a.date > b.date) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});
json = {};
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    json[arr[i].d] = arr[i].v;
}
console.log(json);
```

To sort in descending order swap the return values from the sort function.  Also note that that's not really JSON, it's a javascript object literal.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ccjzzfcr/2/

Comment: Custom sort functions aren't supposed to return a boolean, they need to allow for less than, greater than, _and_ equal to...

Comment: @nnnnnn Excellent reminder, thanks.  Updated answer.

Comment: @SlipperyPete thanks for answering this but it will return date order by ascending.

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO**
[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/hmqezj88/)

> Javascript

```
var json='{"09/03/14":"63.7","09/02/14":"67.4","09/01/14":"67.4","08/29/14":"67.4","08/28/14":"69.4","08/27/14":"69.4","08/26/14":"178","08/25/14":"16.8","08/22/14":"0"}';
var obj= $.parseJSON(json);
for (var prop in obj) {
    $("#res").append("o." + prop + " = " + obj[prop]+"<br />");
     console.log("o." + prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
}
```

> Update 1:

**Sort by date described in this post.**
[Sort object by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date)

Comment: The code shown in the question is already an object, not JSON, so no need to parse it. Where's the code sort by date?